# Can I configure my servlet container's thread management?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, jetty

I'm currently working on an app which is heavily connected to maps. To display a map, we are generating a bunch of tiles in many threads, store them and get them if a user wants to see a certain part of the map.

The problem is, I'm naming threads that generate tiles a certain way, but then, when I want to get tiles to show a map, my servlet container's taking random threads from the pool, so the thread named for generating a tile ends up getting it from the storage. Of course, I could just rename the thread after generating a tile back, but I wonder if there is an alternative.

I wonder if I somehow can configure my servlet container for it to maybe kill threads after some time being idle or to create a new thread where I want to or to allocate several threads to work with this part of the code?

All I could find in terms of configuring servlet container is setting its min and max thread pool size, which I think won't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container is 100% in control over it's threading.

If you are attempting to manipulate the threading of the container then you are fighting a losing battle.

It is not possible to safely kill or stop threads on a running container, as this is incredibly unsafe, and *will lead to many memory issues (leaks) and unclosed resources*.  The `Thread.stop()` method has been deprecated since Java 1.2.

Now that we have the negatives out of the way ...

Jetty is a 100% Async Java Web Server.

The classic assumption that 1 request uses 1 thread is wrong. (if you want this kind of behavior, then you should use Jetty 6 or older.  Jetty versions older than 9.2 are now all EOL / End of Life)

When you use a Servlet call that is traditionally a blocking call, the Jetty server has to fake that blocking call to satisfy the API contract.

Even if using old school / traditional blocking Servlet APIs you'll still experience many situations where that 1 request has been handled by multiple threads over the lifetime of that 1 request.

If you want to work with the Servlet API and it's container then the first thing you should do is start to use both the Servlet Async Processing APIs and Servlet Async I/O APIs combined.  Make sure you read about the gotchas on both APIs!

Async Processing will allow you to handle more processing of requests on the server side, not use the container threads that heavily, allow more control over how the threading behaves, will grant you better control over request timeouts, and even get notified of request/response error cases that you will always deal with on a web server.

Async I/O will allow you to only use a thread if there is content from the request/connection to read or if the connection allows a write.   That connection will not consume a thread unless I/O is possible.  This means more connections/requests per server, and ill behaving clients (slow, dead, problematic, etc) will not impact the behavior of your other clients by consuming threads that are not doing anything productive for you.

If you don't want to work with the Servlet API and do things your own way, then you'll have to manage your own Executor / ThreadGroup / ThreadPool that the server is unaware of.   But that still means you'll need to use the Servlet Async Processing APIs to allow the 2 to coexist in harmony (you'll need to use the AsyncContext to inform the container that you are now taking control over the processing of the request, and then later inform it via the AsyncContext that you are done and the request is complete).

The biggest gotcha with this approach is that you cannot safely write to the HttpServletResponse from a thread that the container wasn't in control over.

Meaning the container dispatched on a thread to your application, that thread is the only one that can safely use the HttpServletResponse to write the response.  You can have a different thread do the processing, a different thread provide the data to the HttpServletResponse, even a different thread that pumps the dispatch thread with content.   But that thread you were dispatched to needs to be used to write.

This is the mixed threading behavior gotcha in the servlet spec. (you are in servlet async mode, on a different thread to process, but not using async mode to read/write.)  It's a terribly complex, and ill defined, behavior in the servlet spec that leads to many issues, and I advise you to not chase this path.

This gotcha goes away if you *also use the Servlet Async I/O APIs*, but at that point the difference in the two above choices is negligible.